# trying to load vue-agile but ParseError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browserify, babelify, envify

I'm building a website using vuejs and trying to load agile-vue to use globally in the vue app. So I added following code into main.js:

```
var VueAgile = require('vue-agile');
Vue.use(VueAgile);
```

Later on I use browserify with babelify and envify to create a bundle.js file. and use the following code to compile:

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -e main.js > bundle.js
```

with the babelify preset 'babel-preset-env' setup in the package.json file. I got the following error:

```
import VueAgile from './Agile.vue'
^ 
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I got rid of the error with adding esmify:

```
 NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -p esmify  -e main.js > bundle.js
```

but I got stuck with a new error:

```
<template>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

I've been searching a while for a solution and I think there is something wrong with browserify not transforming all files (only topfiles, not dependencies) but I have not found how to force it.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Did building work before adding `vue-agile`? i.e. if you don't use vue-agile at all, can you build a basic vue "app"?

Comment: yes, building worked and website worked, I'm using `vueistope`, `vueimagesloaded`, `vue-scrollto` and `vue-carousel`. Its the latter I wanted to replace because of more features.